# Web App Diagnostic Logs: Web server logging as a slot setting

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Is it possible to configure the Web App's Diagnostic Logs "web server logging" storage account to be bound to a slot (i.e. as a slot setting), in order to prevent this during the swap:

[image: These settings will be modified in the destination slot]

The actual value for this is set as a `WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_CONTAINER_URL` app setting variable on the actual Web App, but it is invisible on the portal (meaning one cannot enable 'slot setting').

This is unlike the "application logging" storage account, which is made visible (meaning I can enable slot settings):

[image: App Settings]

I would prefer not to have to do this via cmdlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to enable the "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS" and "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_CONTAINER_URL", I suggest you could try to use azure Resource explorer to change the slot settings.

More details, you could follow below ways.

1.Open the azure Resource explorer and locate your web app.

[image]

[image]

2.Open the web app's slotConfigNames tag.

[image]

3.Add the appsetting name in the properties.

Firstly click the edit and change the properties. At last click the put to save the changes.

[image]

You could find all the slot setting will not miss when using swap.

[image]